Testnet USDC from https://staging.aave.com/faucet/ not showing on Metamask
I am getting Testnet USDC from https://staging.aave.com/faucet/ not showing on Metamask.
I approved the transaction in Metamask.
It is showing on Aave page at USDC Testnet Faucet but not showing on Metamask.
I require to send USDC directly from my Metamask wallet to my smart contract.
results on SEPOLIA ETHERSCAN:
Transaction Hash: 0x2aa782b2acb0c24d0e9ca2a5b72c0b1fe25686b31031ca3c953319f3821570fb
thanks
Uday

You need to add the token you want to display and transfer to Metamask.
https://support.metamask.io/managing-my-tokens/custom-tokens/how-to-display-tokens-in-metamask/#how-to-add-a-custom-token
